# specifying a generic type parameter using a string

Tags: c#

Suppose I have a method

```
public void Whatever<T>() { ... }
```

suppose I have a type in the form of a string

```
var myType = "System.String";
```

Normally, I'd call the method like:

```
Whatever<string>();
```

But I'd like to be able to call it using myType somehow. Is this possible?
I know this doesn't work, but conceptually:

```
Whatever<Type.GetType(myType)>();
```

Comment: Not really. Generics are a compile-time feature, using type metadata is a runtime thing. Any answer along this path is likely to be painful. What are you really needing to do? Because perhaps there is a simpler mechanism.

Comment: How are you going to continue using your `Whatever`?

Comment: Perhaps this question should be edited to read "specifying a generic type parameter using a string", because it is possible to represent a generic type using a string.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Reflection and [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this

Reflect the method that you want to call to get the `MethodInfo`, then make it generic and [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292967.aspx) it.

Something like this (notice that this is from the top of my head (no VS here), it might not be perfect yet but should get you started):

```
Type type = myObject.GetType();
MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("NameOfMethod");
MethodInfo genericMethod = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeOf(string));
genericMethod.Invoke(myObject, new object[] { "theString" } );
```

Comment: This may work (like you, I haven't tried it). But I really don't want to use reflection.

Comment: Then no go, the type of `T` is only available at Runtime, so you can't code against it and expect the compiler to understand what you mean. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an instance via Reflection (or provide both generic and non-generic `Whatever` type). Of course Reflection is slow (and you can have only an object or base class reference). Often the generic type can be just a specialization of the non-generic one.